# Change button link in iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I have a full page website in `iframe` like

```
<head>
    <title>Test Layout</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        body, html
        {
            margin: 0; padding: 0; height: 100%; overflow: hidden;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
        <iframe width="100%" height="100%" src="websitehere" />
</body>
</html>
```

And there is a button in `iframe` that I want to change link. 
I mean if you click that button you go to example.com and want to change it to example2.com .

I have not access to website thats in `iframe` to change codes there

Comment: same orgin with your html?if not , give up

Comment: If the site is on a different domain this is absolutely impossible, for good reason.

Comment: You mean 404 page

Comment: it can be done by overlay with css?

Comment: No, consider an iframe containing a bank login page, it must not be possible for the iframe page to be able to interact with the logon page - to say capture passwords - and browsers are designed to prevent that.